# TimeLine -- Change color when clicked

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am trying to implement a timeline however I can't change the color when I click on one of the different states :( Does anyone know what my problem is or how I can do it?

The idea was to assign a different color to different states, but it didn't work :(

In the image I leave an example of what I am trying to get.

Thank you very much

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li [ngClass]="priority['isComplete']?'complete':''" *ngFor="let priority of Priorities; let  p = index;" (click)="changeTimeline(priority.id)">{{priority.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that when you click on a active state, all other should be changed to inactive, I worked on your StackBlitz to give you and idea on how this could be done.

Please have a look at the forked [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lqmcds?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: OMG, it's perfect !! Can you change the color of the line too? it is red, can you change it according to the state? If the state is yellow, the line turns yellow

Comment: I updated my StackBlitz according to your request. The `CSS` is kind of a hack but at least it demonstrates how it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

In project there is no css class with name: complete. You should modify your priority model and add color field which tell us what color should be button if it is completed. Then set this color to the button using [style.background]. When you use this solution you dont have to add seperate css separate classes for each background color.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xqhg6r)

Comment: You're right now how can I color the different buttons when I click on them? Pressing 3 turns yellow, 1 turns red, as in the picture? Thanks for trying to help me!